# Is there a way to unstake a liquidity token when the frontend of the platform is down?

Tags: uniswap

When a frontend is down, I suspect there would still be a way to unstake an LP token, correct?
Once that's done, I'd also be able to remove liquidity from a uniswap v2 pool.

Any pointers to where I could learn how to do that?

Thanks a ton,
R.

Comment: I am specifically asking for this guy: https://medium.com/@nekofinance/day-one-recap-neko-finance-1710a1482e98

But I am mostly curious how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can interact with the contract directly through etherscan.

First, find the contract address. Then, on the etherscan page of the contract, navigate to this tab: https://etherscan.io/address/0xa1cE056154099D3EeDE7713c6ee8b9eE86A1A708#writeContract (this is a LP pair contract that I took in the medium article that you linked - it may not be the contract that you are looking for). On this page, you can interact directly with the functions of the contract, such as the one that allow to unstake your tokens.

Comment: Thanks. Glad I asked.

It's not worth the fees (for me), but it was a great learning opportunity. I would need to use the "MasterChef" contract, and find the right pool id. I managed to find all the info I need. I don't know if I'll submit the trx cause of the fees, but I might when I see a low gwei, just to confirm that I got it right.